# fail2ban to block Wordpress brute force attacks on wp-login.php

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, wordpress, fail2ban

Is there a way to set up fail to ban to block on IP that hits wp-login too many times?

I have tried adding this jail.local:

```
[apache-wp-login]

enabled = true
action   = iptables[name=wplogin, port=http, protocol=tcp]
           sendmail-whois[name=wplogin, dest=root, sender=fail2ban@example.com]
filter  = apache-wp-login
logpath = /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log
maxretry = 5
```

And then adding a definition in  /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-wp-login.conf:

```
[Definition]

# Option:  failregex
# Notes.:  Regexp to catch Apache dictionary attacks on Wordpress wp-login
# Values:  TEXT
#
failregex = [\w\.\-]+ [\w\.\-]+ .*] "POST /wp-login.php
```

Still getting wp-login attempts way over the maxentry limit... could this be because I'm using combined log format, instead of common?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I modified my WordPress theme functions.php file to add the following:

`add_action('wp_login_failed', 'log_wp_login_fail'); // hook failed login
function log_wp_login_fail($username) {
        error_log("WP login failed for username: $username");
}`

Failed login are now written in my error logs.

My apache-wp-config.conf looks like this:

`[Definition]
failregex =  [[]client <HOST>[]] WP login failed.*
ignoreregex =`

And my jail.local contains the following:

`[apache-wp-login]
enabled  = true
filter   = apache-wp-login
action   = iptables-multiport[name=apache-wp-login, port="http,https"]
           sendmail-whois[name=apache-wp-login, dest=root, sender=fail2ban@example.com]
logpath  = /home/*/logs/*error.log
bantime  = 720
maxretry = 6`

More info at this [site](http://blog.somsip.com/2012/02/using-fail2ban-to-protect-wordpress/)

Comment: awesome, I will give this method a shot, and let you know how it works out :)

Comment: my log directory structure is /var/log/error.log. Using your method, would I use logpath = /var/*/log/*error.log?

Comment: If you have only one error log then just use `logpath = /var/log/error.log`

Comment: Well, this method seems to be working for me :) I'm now getting emails from fail2ban informing me when an IP address is blocked. Thank you!